# Migration using EF code first causes error

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When I do migrations using EF code first it shows me this error:

> "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')"

```json
"ConnectionString":
{
      "Default": "Server=MUBIN\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=Vegangular; Integrated Security=true;"
}
```

```cs
services.AddDbContext<VegaDbContext>(Options => 
    Options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ConnectionStrings` is a plural, so you're missing the "s" from the end:

```
"ConnectionStrings": { "Default": "Server=MUBIN\SQLEXPRESS; Database=Vegangular; Integrated Security=true;" }
```

See the [article here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/connection-strings) using conection strings.

If you look at the documentation for [ConnectionStrings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1), you'll see that the property is of type `System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettingsCollection`, hence the plural.